# Use an USB tethered phone as network adapter

Tags: networking, usb

I am running CentOS 6 and was able to tether my HTC phone using a proxy called [proxoid](http://code.google.com/p/proxoid/) . This allows me to redirect HTTP. But how do I redirect the entire TCP traffic, e.g. if I need to setup openvpn connection to my VPN server?

It seems it can be done because software similar to proxoid (exactly same principles, e.g. [easytether](http://www.mobile-stream.com/easytether/android.html)), which  sets up network adapter. I couldn't find anything on internet perhaps because I don't have the right keywords - maybe this is a virtual network adapter that I am trying to setup?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With my HTC WildFire and my [archlinux](/questions/tagged/archlinux), I just have to enable USB tethering and then plug the USB cable into both my PC and the device. Then in a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) as root run the following commands:

```
# modprobe usbnet # if not already loaded
# ip link set usb0 up && dhcpcd usb0
```

if you don't have `dhcpcd`, try typing `dhc`<kbd>tab</kbd>.

If no problem occurs, you'll be able to list interfaces and IP with:

```
$ ip a s
```

and you will see a line for `usb0` (or such).

See [wiki archlinux Android Tethering](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Android_Tethering#USB_tethering)

Answer (score 2):

Under Fedora some phones get recognized and appear directly under the NetworkManager menu (my Samsung Galaxy and now Galaxy III get recognized immediately). CentOS 6 is similar to recent Fedora, this should also work (specially if you got it to work as you say). Just make sure that the tethering is configured in the phone.