# How to activate reverse tethering on CentOS 5

Tags: centos, usb

Most examples for reverse tethering are for Ubuntu. They go something along these lines:

2. Attach smartphone
3. Configure usb0
4. Start reverse tethering on the smartphone
5. Use the PC network via USB from your smartphone

Now I do not want to use Ubuntu. I want to use CentOS 5. I've got the CentOS 5 Plus XEN Kernel active, so some features should be available there, too.

So far I found that I will probably have to:

- Actiate the kernel-module `rndis_host`, that will enable
- `usbnet` and that should make
- `usb0` appear as network device

The latter does not happen, `lsusb` shows the correct tags for my attached smartphone.

What am I missing here?

There has been a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49567/how-do-you-access-internet-in-rhel-5-using-android-smartphone-usb-lan), but the question is not that "on the mark" and also doesn't have any answers yet either.

Comment: Did you try doing this? I'm not sure why it wouldn't work using any Linux distro vs. Ubuntu.

Comment: @slm Yes I did try. I suspect that there is something more or newer in Ubuntu.

Comment: Given CentOS 5's age I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: This seems like a dup to your Q. Can you confirm please? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68181/use-an-usb-tethered-phone-as-network-adapter

Comment: @slm that Q is about co6. So the version of the kernel driver seems to be important indeed.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, wasn't sure if the approach was the same of different. So that doesn't work on co5 then?

Comment: Just a thought but I came across this blog post for Fedora 13 which showed an alternative method which might also work for you on co5: http://idolinux.blogspot.com/2010/06/usb-tether-android-with-linux.html

Comment: @slm azilink-app sounds good. I already thought about using adb for this. I can propably be done via commandline, too - I will look into that - it will help achieve my goal, but does not answer my q. Mabe I will delve into the change log of the above mentioned modules later on...